Classification of binary associative operations on $\mathbb{R}^n$
Is there an explicit characterization of associative binary operations on two vectors of the same dimension?
Some examples include component wise +/*/max, or matrix multiplication if the vectors can be viewed as square matrices or elements of an upper/lower triangular matrix. But these don’t feel exhaustive.
The question will have interesting implications in advancing State space models that became a strong contender of transformer architectures in large language models or sequence models, since associative operations can be parallelized efficiently on cuda via the associative scan primitive operation.

Start by reading https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra. You will find there references to a number of classification theorems.

@MoisheKohan thanks! Where does the min/max operation fit into the general framework?

It violates associative algebra axioms.

Please do not change your original question. It makes my answer irrelevant. Instead, ask a new question.

Sadly, your question is hopeless, since the cardinality of the set of all semigroups defined on $\Bbb{R}^n$ is $2^\mathfrak{c}$.
Upper bound. A multiplication on $\Bbb{R}^n$ is a map $\Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$. Since $|\Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^n| = |\Bbb{R}^n| = |\Bbb{R}| = \mathfrak{c}$, there are at most $\mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c}$ possible multiplications. But $\mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c} = 2^\mathfrak{c}$, as shown in this answer.
Lower bound. Let me prove the lower bound for $n= 1$. It relies on a standard trick for enumerating semigroups, see for instance [1], a highly instructive paper.
Let $E = {\Bbb R} \setminus \{0, 1\}$. If $f: E \times E \to \{0, 1\}$ is a map, one can define a multiplication on $\Bbb R$ by setting
$$
xy = 
\begin{cases}
  f(x,y) &\text{if $x, y \in E$} \\
  0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Associativity is easy to verify since $(xy)z = x(yz) = 0$ for all $x, y, z$. Since the cardinal of the set of functions from $E \times E$ to $\{0, 1\}$ is $2^\mathfrak{c}$, this gives the desired lower bound.
[1] Distler, Andreas; Mitchell, J. D.
The number of nilpotent semigroups of degree 3.
Electron. J. Combin. 19 (2012), no. 2, Paper 51, 19 pp.

Thanks. I should ask about weakly differentiable maps instead.
